# Compiler bug in Visual C++ 2012? (Messed up jump addresses)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-construction

Compiling this completely without optimization

```
void Add(T data)
{
    node<T> *pNode = new node<T>;
    pNode->m_pNext = NULL;
    pNode->m_data = data;

    uint32_t cPushes;
    uint32_t cPops;
    node<T> *pTail;

    while (true)
    {
        cPushes = m_cPushes;
        cPops = m_cPops;
        pTail = (node<T>*)m_pTail;
        if (cPushes != m_cPushes)
            continue;

        if (!pTail)
            if (CAS2(&m_pTail, NULL, cPushes, (uint32_t)pNode, cPushes +1))
                break;
        else if (CAS(&pTail->m_pNext, NULL, (uint32_t)pNode))
                break;
        else
            CAS2(&m_pTail, (uint32_t)pTail, cPushes, (uint32_t)pTail->m_pNext, cPushes + 1);
    }

    CAS2(&m_pHead, NULL, cPops, (uint32_t)pNode, cPops + 1);
    CAS2(&m_pTail, (uint32_t)pTail, cPushes, (uint32_t)pNode, cPushes + 1);
}
```

Disassembly: http://pastebin.com/7EaH3whu (pastebinned because its huge and it somehow breaks SO's code tags)

If you look at it, about every jump instruction have their addresses mixed up

For example, if this statement fails: 'if (!pTail)', instead of continuing at the 'else if', it jumps back to the start of the loop (actually, it jumps to a jump that jumps to the start of the loop)

Full code: http://pastebin.com/U5qGgT0E

Comment: `if ... if ... else` is parsing ambiguity. I forget how C++ resolves it, but you should put braces around them in case that's causing it.

Comment: Known as the [Dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) issue, this is why I believe than whitespace sensitive languages (such as Python) lie *less*.

Comment: @Pubby The `else` always belongs to the most recent unclosed `if`.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Every time you think you have found a compiler bug, you haven't.

Comment: +1 for your thoroughness. Disassmbling the code to find this is killing a fly with a cannon

Answer (score 8):

```
    if (!pTail)
        if (CAS2(&m_pTail, NULL, cPushes, (uint32_t)pNode, cPushes +1))
            break;
    else if (CAS(&pTail->m_pNext, NULL, (uint32_t)pNode))
            break;
    else
        CAS2(&m_pTail, (uint32_t)pTail, cPushes, (uint32_t)pTail->m_pNext, cPushes + 1);
```

is really

```
    if (!pTail) {
        if (CAS2(&m_pTail, NULL, cPushes, (uint32_t)pNode, cPushes +1)) {
            break;
        } else if (CAS(&pTail->m_pNext, NULL, (uint32_t)pNode)) {
            break;
        } else {
            CAS2(&m_pTail, (uint32_t)pTail, cPushes, (uint32_t)pTail->m_pNext, cPushes + 1);
        }
    }
```

Is that what the jumps do? I bet.

Comment: Seems so, I shouldent be coding after being up to 6 AM

Comment: Ah, that ;) No, you shouldn't. At least not without a huge dose of caffeine.

Comment: Braces and parenthesis are your friends and can keep you out of tons of trouble!  I still remember the "compiler bug" I ran into as the result of not using parenthesis to enforce proper operator order.  Made me a true believer in less ain't more, more is more when it comes to brace/parenthesis.

Comment: @RichardChambers: Which is why I sometimes wonder if operator precedence really is worth it... the more complex the rules of which precedes which and the less clear it is when reading a program whether the precedence is intentional or the original writer slipped...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I never understand this attitude. If the code works the presumption must surely be that the author was competent.

Comment: @EJP: *If the code works* is a big assumption, esp. during a bug hunt! How do *you* know it works ? Hell, even when *I* wrote the code I am not sure a couple months later whether it's really what I meant!